# Convert one level object to nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

So, given this structure of object:

```
{
   property1: 'value1',
   property2.property3: 'value2',
   property2.property7: 'value4',
   property4.property5.property6: 'value3',

}
```

Need to be converted to this look:

```
{
   property1: 'value1',
   property2: { 
                property3: 'value2',
                property7: 'value4'
              },
   property4: { 
                property5: { 
                             property6: 'value3'
                           }
              }
}
```

Just simple example. I'd like to see most optimized and beautiful solution. Obviously it should be function that takes first object as input and outputs second. 
Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: [you haven't shown what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and it's not my job to do your work for you.

Comment: zzzzBov, Look. If you are not interest than just ignore it. Why to complain, I dont understand? For some people it might be interesting.

Comment: Nearly all people on SO, myself included, would respond the same way, Pol. This site is generally helpful if you have specific issue or question when coding your own solution to a problem. It is unhelpful when you ask somebody else to write that same solution for you.

Comment: I want to see more minuses come on guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rough implementation can be

```
function convert(obj) {
    var res = {}, i, j, splits, ref, key;
    for (i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            splits = i.split('.');
            ref = res;
            for (j = 0; j < splits.length; j++) {
                key = splits[j];
                if (j == splits.length - 1) {
                    ref[key] = obj[i];
                } else {
                    ref = ref[key] = ref[key] || {};
                }
            }
        };
    }
    return res;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gJkc6/)

Comment: I'm following. Thanks.